# SetHeading didn't work for BingMap Control

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I got compass data and would to rotate map toward moving but SetHeading do nothing for me.

It said to "Make sure that RotationEnabled is set to true". But it equals false and has not setter.

Please, advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Heading works only for Birds Eye mode and could accept only Nx90 values.